# Excel VBA is not opening recordset

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have an ADODB recordset that up until the other day was working perfectly. Now it will not open even for one line of code. I have double checked that the data is there to be extracted. I should only get one record every time it is run. I have several other recordsets that pull data from the same worksheet just fine and they are set up to run the exact same way so I am not sure what the issue is. It is setup as below:

```vb
Dim Vals as new adodb.recordset
Dim StrSql as string
Dim MN as string

StrSql = "SELECT DISTINCT [SampleWorksheet].[Price] WHERE [SampleWorksheet].[Model] = '" & MN

If Vals.State = 1 Then Vals.Close
vals.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic


Vals.close
```

I have tried to open with set vals = cnn.execute but the recordset refuses to open. It does not error out it just loops forever since it is within a Do While Not Vals.EOF and it never reaches the EOF because it is not open. The connection is setup to run against itself and works correctly in all of my files.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may try

```vb
Dim Vals as adodb.recordset

StrSql = "SELECT DISTINCT Price FROM SampleWorksheet WHERE Model = '" & MN & "'"
Set Vals = cnn.execute(StrSql)
```

Comment: That, and drop the `New` in `Vals As New ADODB.Recordset`